# How to get the sum of elements in two different lists in a DataFrame instead of concatenation in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have a DataFrame that contains two columns, 'A_List' and 'B_List', which are of the string dtype. I have converted these to lists and I would like to now perform element wise addition of the elements in the lists at specific indices. I have attached an example of the csv file I'm using. When I do the following, I am getting an output that is joining the elements at the specified indices as opposed to finding their sum. What may I try differently to achieve the sum instead?

[image]

For example, when I do `row["A_List"][0] + row["B_List"][3]`, the desired output would be 0.16 (since 0.1+0.06 = 0.16). Instead, I am getting `0.10.06` as my answer.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Example.csv')

# Get  rid of the brackets []
df["A_List"] = df["A_List"].apply(lambda x: x.strip("[]"))
df["B_List"] = df["B_List"].apply(lambda x: x.strip("[]"))

# Convert the string dtype of values into a list
df["A_List"] = df["A_List"].apply(lambda x: x.split())
df["B_List"] = df["B_List"].apply(lambda x: x.split())

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row["A_List"][0] + row["B_List"][3])
```

Comment: read up on "tidy" data. storing collections as elements of a dataframe is an anti-pattern. In any case, you're working with strings, not even lists of a strings or lists of numbers.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible input? For instance the return of `df.to_dict('list')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn the individual values into floats when parsing your string lists.

In one step, you can do the following with [`DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) which applies the given function to every element one at a time, and a lambda containing a list comprehension around `str.strip` and `str.split`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A_List": ["[0.1 0.2 0.3]", "[1.1 1.2 1.3]"],
        "B_List": ["[0.9 0.8 0.7]", "[0.4 0.3 0.2]"],
    }
)

df[["A_List", "B_List"]] = df[["A_List", "B_List"]].applymap(
    lambda x: [float(v) for v in x.strip("[]").split()]
)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row["A_List"][0] + row["B_List"][2])
```

prints

```py
0.7999999999999999
1.3
```